# How do I capture changes in canvas.offsetLeft, canvas.offsetTop in Dart?

Tags: css, canvas, dart

In my test code, below, I want to update mbox.style.left according canvas.offsetLeft, but the function repositionBox() is not called when the canvas is repositioned due to layout changes. Any hint on how to detect changes in canvas.offsetLeft ? (The same question applies to canvas.offsetTop as well.)

```
DivElement createMessagebox(String id, CanvasElement c) {

  DivElement mbox = new DivElement();
  mbox.id = id;

  int left = 10 + canvas.offsetLeft;
  int top  = 28 + canvas.offsetTop;

  mbox.style.border = '2px solid #FFF';
  mbox.style.zIndex = "1";
  mbox.style.position = "absolute";
  mbox.style.width = "300px";
  mbox.style.color = "lightgreen";
  mbox.style.background = "rgba(50,50,50,0.7)";
  mbox.style.textAlign = "left";
  mbox.style.padding = "2px";
  mbox.style.fontSize = 'x-small';

  void repositionBox(Event e) {
    int left = 10 + canvas.offsetLeft;
    int top  = 28 + canvas.offsetTop;

    mbox.style.left = "${left}px";
    mbox.style.top = "${top}px";

    print("repositionBox: event=$e: left=${mbox.style.left} top=${mbox.style.top}");
  }

  repositionBox(null);

  c.onChange.listen(repositionBox);

  return mbox;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to detect changes to these values directly afaik, certainly not cross browser, which leaves you with two options:

1. Create a wrapper div around your canvas and messagebox, and position: absolute both the canvas and your message box.  This lets the layout engine deal with it, and will react as efficiently as the display updates. (Strongly recommended unless you have other needs not specified).
2. Use a timer to poll for changes to this property, and fire a custom event to handle it.  This will lag behind the display update though, plus consume cpu when idle (proportionally to how snappily you want it to update), this is not ideal, but things like http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/ rely on this method.  For extra points you could possibly use a combination of requestAnimationFrame/setTimeout to do this in a way that doesn't burn cycles when the tab is not focused, but I'm speculating and haven't tried this myself.